# Max Age < 0 not supported by Rest-Assured

Tags: java, cookies, playframework, rest-assured

In Cookie.java it throws an exception when we send cookie with max-age as negative for expiring the cookie.

As is clear in their code

```
/**
 * Set the maximum age of the cookie, specified in seconds,
 * By default, <code>-1</code> indicating the cookie will persist
 * until browser shutdown.
 *
 * @return   an integer specifying the maximum age of the
 *              cookie in seconds; if negative, means
 *              the cookie persists until browser shutdown
 */
public Builder setMaxAge(int maxAge) {
    if(maxAge < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Max-Age cannot be less than 0");
    }
    this.maxAge = maxAge;
    return this;
}
```

The comments however supports a negative value though and clearly indicates negative value means the cookie persists until browser shutdown.

Is their any way around where I can send a cookie in response with a negative value for max-age as the issue is not yet handled in their code?

Comment: are you able to modify the `cookie.jar`?

Comment: I don't want to modify the third party library

Comment: then you should tell this to the one who has written the library, since it is clearly his fault

Comment: Maybe a case of "read the code, the documentation lies" ;)

Comment: Well, either you fix that library yourself, or you wait until [this problem is resolved](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/issues/580) (but it doesn't look like someone of the developers cares about that bug).

Comment: This should be addressed in version 3.0.0